# Kotlin coroutine suspend and delay

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I want to simulate file loading and I want to delay code for 4 seconds and I can't do this.

```
 suspend fun showLoadingProgress() : String = suspendCancellableCoroutine{ continuation ->

    while (fileIsBeingLoaded())
    {
        delay(4000)

        val percent = ((loadedBites.toDouble() / fileBites.toDouble())*100).toInt()

        continuation.resume("$loadedBites/$fileBites ($percent%)")
    }
}
```

I have error that: suspension functions can be called only from coroutine body. BUT

When I have code like this, without returning String, then my delay works.. WHY?:

```
   suspend fun showLoadingProgress() {

    while (fileIsBeingLoaded())
    {
        delay(4000)

        val percent = ((loadedBites.toDouble() / fileBites.toDouble())*100).toInt()

        continuation.resume("$loadedBites/$fileBites ($percent%)")
    }
}
```

How can I make delay and return a String?

Comment: I guess in your second ("working") example you shouldn't have `continuation.resume()`, right?

Comment: Your code contradicts itself in a way. Do you want to return a single string? Or do you want to emit multiple strings in a loop? Here you have a loop and yet return a single string, which doesn't make much sense conceptually (even without looking at the code in details). If you want to emit multiple values, consider removing the `suspend` keyword, and return a `Flow<String>` instead. You'll have to use something like [flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow.html) instead of `suspendCancellableCoroutine`

Comment: @Joffrey It's correct! I needed connect suspend and Flow to emit changing progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`suspendCancellableCoroutine` is mainly used with callbacks to suspend a coroutine execution until the callback fires, for example:

```
suspend fun getUser(id: String): User = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
          Api.getUser(id) { user ->
              continuation.resume(user)
          }
          continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
              // clear some resources, cancel tasks, close streams etc.
          }
    }
```

`delay` doesn't work in `suspendCancellableCoroutine` block because it is not marked as `suspend` and therefore we can't call `suspend` function in it. `suspendCancellableCoroutine` function is defined like:

```
public suspend inline fun <T> suspendCancellableCoroutine(
    crossinline block: (CancellableContinuation<T>) -> Unit
): T = ...
```

If it was defined something like this (please note `block` marked as `suspend`):

```
public suspend inline fun <T> suspendCancellableCoroutine(
    crossinline block: suspend (CancellableContinuation<T>) -> Unit
): T = ...
```

then we would be able to call `delay` function in it.

---

I don't know why you use `while` loop, it seems it is redundant there. Or you use it incorrectly for the loading progress.

You don't have callbacks, so you can get rid of `suspendCancellableCoroutine`:

```
suspend fun getLoadingProgress(): String {
    delay(4000)
    val percent = ((loadedBites.toDouble() / fileBites.toDouble())*100).toInt()
    return "$loadedBites/$fileBites ($percent%)"
}

suspend fun showLoadingProgress() {
    while (fileIsBeingLoaded()) {
        val progress = getLoadingProgress()
        // use progress
    }
}
```

---

Another approach is to use `Flow` to emit the loading progress. It will look something like the following using [`flow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow.html) builder:

```
fun getLoadingProgress(): Flow<String> = flow {
    while (fileIsBeingLoaded()) {
        delay(4000)
        val percent = ((loadedBites.toDouble() / fileBites.toDouble())*100).toInt()
        emit("$loadedBites/$fileBites ($percent%)")
    }
}
```

And collect values:

```
someCoroutineScope.launch {
    getLoadingProgress().collect { progress ->
        // use progress
    }
}
```

Comment: Flow works perfect. Thanks. But my code works even when I add supsend with Flow. What is different when I ude suspend and dont with Flow?

Comment: You don't need to use `suspend` with `flow` block, `flow` is not a suspend function. The function should be marked with `suspend` keyword if it calls another `suspend` function. In this case `getLoadingProgress` only calls `flow` function, which is not a `suspend` function.